# Чёрный экран при запуске linux

Tags: linux, fedora, install, gnome, xorg

Хочу поставить на новый ноутбук asus линукс fedora 30. При загрузке с флешки на стадии запуска окружения GNOME всё останавливается появляется мигающий курсор на чёрном экране а потом просто чёрный экран.

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Была аналогичная проблема в `CentOS 7.6` с `gdm 3.28` после авторизации в `X`. Похоже, что это глюк `gdm`.

1. Открываем вторую консоль: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Запускаем `htop`, находим `X` процесс и посылаем ему `SIGTERM`.

   - <kbd>F4</kbd> набираем `gdm` - чтобы найти `X` процесс
   - <kbd>F9</kbd> ⇒ `SIGTERM`
3. `X Window` перезапустится и со второй попытки `gdm` будет работать нормально.
4. Для входа в систему без авторизации можно добавить в `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

   ```
    AutomaticLogin=username
    AutomaticLoginEnable=True
   ```

---

Дополнительно:

- `gdm` для `gnome`.
- `lightdm` для `xfce`.
- `lxdm` для `lxde`.

Comment: Чем этот способ отличается от обычной перезагрузки устройства?

Comment: `htop` установленного по дефолту в Fedora/CentOS/RHEL - нет. Надо либо доустанавливать, либо пользоваться дефолтным `top`. В CentOS для его установки надо будет ещё подтягивать репо epel. Ну конечно если было всё установлено заранее и пользователь юзает `htop`, а не тот же `glances` для подобных задач, или ему и `top` достаточно, то конечно способ интересный

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке граб меню я нажал E и там в строке с началом линукс в конце через пробел написал nomodeset и нажал f10 и все заработало